# How soon (after your first credit card statement ever) do you get a credit file/history in Canada?

Tags: canada, credit-card, loans, credit-score, credit-history

How many days after your first credit card statement EVER does one get a credit report on file with one of the two Canadian bureaus? I'm trying to develop Canadian credit on my first credit card and I want to know how soon will I have a credit file to use for other applications?

Comment: As Dilip says, it'll take a while for your credit report to be useful. I don't know about Canada, but it took me nearly 18 months to generate a decent credit "file" here in the US.

Comment: Oh my...18 months is what bureaus require?!  So I guess I can't apply for another Canadian credit card anytime soon?

Comment: Some US banks require 24 months of credit history before using it for credit decision. The situation might be similar in Canada.